# Reading cookies from a different domain with CSP

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, cross-domain, content-security-policy

I am setting a secure, http only, same site none cookie on [www.domain-a.org](http://www.domain-a.org) express server. Using CORS and CSP I want to fetch that cookie from [www.domain-b.com](http://www.domain-b.com) which also uses express. Every time a user lands on domain-b, it will make a fetch request on the server to domain-a to get its cookie.

This is my example code below for testing purposes but it's not working. When I try to fetch domain-a cookie from domain-b I get back an empty object. Are these requests possible?

**domain-a.org**

With CORS I've set up these policies on my send-cookie route so that domain-b is only allowed to call the endpoint and request the cookie from domain-a:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'https://www.domain-b.com'
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ['GET','OPTIONS']
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
```

```
router.get('/set-cookie', (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('domain-a-cookie', 'domain-a-value', {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true,
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
  })

  res.send('set domain-a cookie')
})

router.get('/send-cookie', cors({ origin: 'https://www.domain-b.com', methods: ['GET','OPTIONS'], credentials: true, preflightContinue: true}), (req, res) => {
  const response = {
    status: 'success'
  }

  if (req.cookies && req.cookies['domain-a-cookie']) {
    response.data = {
      cookie: req.cookies['domain-a-cookie']
    }
  }

  res.status(200).send(response)
})
```

**domain-b.com**

```
router.get('/get-cookie', (req, res) => {
  fetch('https://www.domain-a.org/send-cookie', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include'
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
      }

      return Promise.reject(response)
    })
    .then(result => {
      if (result.status === 'success' && result.data && result.data.cookie) {
        res.cookie('domain-b-cookie', result.data.cookie, {
          httpOnly: true,
          sameSite: 'none',
          secure: true,
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
        })

        res.status(200).send({ status: 'success' })
      } else {
        res.status(500).send(result)
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send(error)
    })
})
```

Comment: You've given quite a lot of code, but not a lot of explanation as to what is going on here. It would help if you described what happened — step by step — when you ran this code and how that is different from what you expect. Adding some additional `console.log` statements would probably help you do this.

Comment: In particular, it would help if you told us where the entry point to this system is. Some HTTP client is making an HTTP request to *one* of the various endpoints (but it isn't clear which one) and that might trigger one of your server side code functions to make an HTTP request to the other server side program. Please layout the sequence of requests and their initiators.

Comment: You mention a CSP (but haven't shown us one) and you have a bunch of explicit CORS related code — but the only code you've shown us for making HTTP requests is *server-side code* doesn't impose restrictions on itself due to either of those because it isn't a browser.

Comment: ```fetch('https://www.domain-a.org/send-cookie', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include'
  })``` — It looks like you expect that code to send a cookie in an HTTP request to *domain-a*. Where do you expect that cookie to come from in the first place?

Comment: Note, that as I mentioned previously, **server side code doesn't restrict itself with CORS** so `mode: 'cors'` and `credentials: 'include'` are pointless. `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, meanwhile, is **just wrong** since you are making a GET request with no request body to describe the type of.

Comment: @Quentin The purpose behind my question is so I can figure out if it's possible to share and persist user sessions between 2 different domains with cookies. If a user logs in to www.domain-a.org, can I share that session and automatically log in that user on www.domain-b.com? When a user lands on domain-b, it will make a fetch request on the server to domain-a to retrieve that cookie and automatically login the user on domain-b if that cookie exists. Sorry if things weren't clear enough. Hope that helps explain everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a user logs in to [www.domain-a.org](http://www.domain-a.org), can I share that session and automatically log in that user on [www.domain-b.com](http://www.domain-b.com)?

Not with your approach.

This is a very simple view of how cookies work for authentication:

1. The user logs in to [www.domain-a.org](http://www.domain-a.org)
2. The user's browser stores a cookie with evidence that they are logged in
3. Whenever they visit [www.domain-a.org](http://www.domain-a.org) the browser sends that evidence to [www.domain-a.org](http://www.domain-a.org)

Later the user visits [www.domain-b.org](http://www.domain-b.org). The browser does **not** send the cookie to [www.domain-b.org](http://www.domain-b.org) because it is a different website. It would be a horrible security problem if I logged into my online banking, then I visited your website and my browser sent you my bank's cookies. I don't know you. I certainly don't trust you with my bank account.

Your server side code makes a request to [www.domain-a.org](http://www.domain-a.org). It isn't sending the cookie stored in the browser. It isn't the browser. It doesn't have that cookie. It would be a security nightmare if the browser had handed that cookie over.

---

A general approach to doing single sign on would be:

1. The user logs in to [www.domain-a.org](http://www.domain-a.org)
2. The user's browser stores a cookie with evidence that they are logged in
3. The user visits [www.domain-b.org](http://www.domain-b.org) which sends them a session cookie to identify them
4. B presents the user with an option to use A to authenticate and the user picks that option by clicking on a link to (e.g.) `http://www.domain-a.org/sso?redirect=http://www.domain-a.org/login`
5. The user visits `http://www.domain-a.org/sso?redirect=http://www.domain-b.org/login` which provides them with a prompt "Do you want to share your personal data with B?"
6. They click yes and are sent to `http://www.domain-b.org/login?token=some-auto-generated-token`
7. B then uses server side code to make an HTTP request to A asking "Is some-auto-generated-token? Can I have their personal data?"
8. A sends the personal data to B
9. B (finally) responds to the request (from step 6) going "Hi! I know who you are now.

Yes. This is relatively complicated. There are a lot of checks. You're dealing with authentication/authorization here. Security is paramount.

The standard for this is [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). [Password.js](https://www.passportjs.org/) has some features for acting as an OAuth client for Node.js.